# Product version of Möbius Inversion formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

I am currently learning about Möbius Inversion. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) , the sum version is proved using convolutions which I can follow along with. However, it also lists a product version of this formula:

$g(n)= \Pi_{d|n} f(d)$ iff $f(n)=\Pi_{d|n}  g(\frac{n}{d})^{\mu(d)}$

I want to know how you can prove this statement. I cannot see how I could use convolutions for this since they involve sums and this one needs products. Is there some theorem/technique I should be utilizing for this?

Comment: Take $\log$ and apply regular inversion formula to $\log g$ and $\log f$.

Comment: What about negative values of $f$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger I believe convolutions are defined with domains of only positive integers?

Comment: No, that cannot be the case since for example the Möbius function itself takes also negative values.

Comment: @Meow The comment of Jens Schwaiger ask for the negative **values** of $f$, the values of a function are in the codomain, not in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

One can try to rewrite $\prod_{d|n}  g(\frac{n}{d})^{\mu(d)}$,

$\prod_{d|n}  g(\frac{n}{d})^{\mu(d)}=\prod_{d|n}  
(\prod_{d'|\frac{n}{d}} f(d'))^{\mu(d)}\\
=\prod_{d'|n}\prod_{d|\frac{n}{d'}}f(d')^{\mu(d)}=\prod_{d'|n}f(d')^{\sum_{d|\frac{n}{d'}}\mu(d) }$.

But $\sum_{d|\frac{n}{d'}}\mu(d)=0$ if $\frac{n}{d'}\not=1$ and $=1$ otherwise.

Thus $\prod_{d|n}  g(\frac{n}{d})^{\mu(d)}=f(n)^1=f(n)$.